# htaccess made a full damage to my site, using opencart 3

Tags: opencart-3

i've got a strange error ... my site was working well i've tried to make some modification on htaccess file to stop 404 error but now i can't access to my site i got this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_file1() in /home3/XXXX/public_html/XXX/store/index.php on line 6
i can access to my admin panel and everything is working fine

this is what i've add to htsaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404/
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500/
# or map them to one error document:
# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
# ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]

# or map them to one error document:
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/error_redirect.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> undefined function is_file1()

There is no such function, I'm not sure how it got like this but remove the 1 - the correct function is called "is_file()".